# I'm facing some error in my signup with active email form using php and error teg not showing any error but in inspect

Tags: php, html, ajax

This is my code. It's a php signup form and it's connection with database all form working but when I click submit then it's not submitting and not showing any error not in same time and also in server error file.

it's show error in inspect that is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
>       at signup (signup.php:51)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (signup.php:129)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["u"])){
    //all include files working.
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
    $p = $_POST['p'];
    $g = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['g']);
    $c = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['c']);
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    // DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR USERNAME AND EMAIL
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $u_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // -------------------------------------------
    Error Line
    // -------------------------------------------
    **$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$e' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);** 
    //Useing for Error handing 
    if (false === $query) {
        echo mysql_error();
    }else{
        echo "Done";
    }
    // -------------------------------------------
       ^^ This is error code
    // -------------------------------------------
    $e_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    if($u == "" || $e == "" || $p == "" || $g == "" || $c == ""){
        echo "The form submission is missing values.";
        exit();
    } else if ($u_check > 0){ 
        echo "The username you entered is alreay taken";
        exit();
    } else if ($e_check > 0){ 
        echo "That email address is already in use in the system";
        exit();
    } else if (strlen($u) < 3 || strlen($u) > 16) {
        echo "Username must be between 3 and 16 characters";
        exit(); 
    } else if (is_numeric($u[0])) {
        echo 'Username cannot begin with a number';
        exit();
    } else {
        // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
        // Begin Insertion of data into the database
        // Hash the password and apply your own mysterious unique salt
        $cryptpass = crypt($p);
        include_once ("php_includes/randStrGen.php");
        $p_hash = randStrGen(20)."$cryptpass".randStrGen(20);
        // Add user info into the database table for the main site table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, gender, country, ip, signup, lastlogin, notescheck)  VALUES('$u','$e','$p_hash','$g','$c','$ip',now(),now(),now())";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
        $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
        // Establish their row in the useroptions table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO useroptions (id, username, background) VALUES ('$uid','$u','original')";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        // Create directory(folder) to hold each user's files(pics, MP3s, etc.)
        if (!file_exists("user/$u")) {
            mkdir("user/$u", 0755);
        }
        // Email the user their activation link
        $to = "$e";                          
        $from = "xyz@xxxxxxxxxx.com";
        $subject = 'yoursitename Account Activation';
        $message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>yoursitename Message</title></head><body style="margin:0px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;"><div style="padding:10px; background:#333; font-size:24px; color:#CCC;"><a href="http://www.yoursitename.com"><img src="http://www.yoursitename.com/images/logo.png" width="36" height="30" alt="yoursitename" style="border:none; float:left;"></a>yoursitename Account Activation</div><div style="padding:24px; font-size:17px;">Hello '.$u.',<br /><br />Click the link below to activate your account when ready:<br /><br /><a href="http://www.yoursitename.com/activation.php?id='.$uid.'&u='.$u.'&e='.$e.'&p='.$p_hash.'">Click here to activate your account now</a><br /><br />Login after successful activation using your:<br />* E-mail Address: <b>'.$e.'</b></div></body></html>';
        $headers = "From: $from\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        echo "signup_success";
        exit();
    }
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: Please add your register form so that anyone can you help you.

Comment: Also, your TypeError happens in JavaScript code on your page, so you should also post that